# android, send e-mail, widget

Tags: android, email, widget

How to send e-mail using widget in android? In my `onUpdate()` method I've written the following:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent3.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            intent3.setType("text/plain");
            intent3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
            intent3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Temat");
            intent3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Tekst wiadomości");

            PendingIntent pendingEmailIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent3,0);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.email_button,pendingEmailIntent);
```

Other actions, like opening new activity or a browser, work as suspected, but this one not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want to use a `mailto:` `Uri`, use `ACTION_SENDTO`, not `ACTION_SEND`.

Comment: I've changed that one, but still not working.

Comment: Check LogCat and see if there's a stack trace or other messages, probably at warning severity. You might need to add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to the `Intent`, for example, and that should show up in LogCat.

Comment: In `logcat` I only get the message: `I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.SENDTO typ=text/plain flg=0x10000000 bnds=[324,352][420,448] (has extras)} from uid 10060 on display 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. There was no errors in code, but apparently, the e-mail app should be run in a different way. I've noticed in many posts that it is called like `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intentname,"OptionalTitle"))`. And, by the way, there's no need for `ACTION_SENDTO`, it works with `ACTION_SEND` now.

Then I've changed my code to:

```
Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent3.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            intent3.setType("text/plain");
            intent3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"abc@gmail.com"});
            intent3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Temat");
            intent3.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Tekst wiadomości");

            PendingIntent pendingEmailIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,Intent.createChooser(intent3,"Choose"),0);

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.email_button,pendingEmailIntent);
```